# Remove optgroup label "0" in form dropdown using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

```
       $select = array(
       'Select Customer' => 'Select Customer',
         $customer_id
            );

        echo form_dropdown(array('name' =>'customer_id' )  , $select);
```

I want to add 'Select Customer' before select but there is "0" in dropdown list. How do I remove it?

Comment: you can remove element with value 0. `unset($cusomer_id[0]);`

Comment: where i put that?

Comment: Please don't remove everything from your question. I have rolled back the changes.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_dropdown

When you can update your question with your controller and model.

In your controller or model code you might have `[]` that will cause the optgroup to show.

Code Example

```
$this->load->helper('form');

$customer[] = array(
  '0' => 'Select Customer',
  '1' => 'John',
  '2' => 'Matthew',
  '3' => 'Luke'
);

$data['customer'] = $customer;

$this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

View

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('name', $customer, '', array('class' => 'form-control'));?>
```

> By removing `[]` will remove the optgroup `0`

Code Example

```
$this->load->helper('form');

$customer = array(
  '0' => 'Select Customer',
  '1' => 'John',
  '2' => 'Matthew',
  '3' => 'Luke'
);

$data['customer'] = $customer;

$this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

View

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('name', $customer, '', array('class' => 'form-control'));?>
```